# Физически стек находится в памяти?

Tags: терминология

А под памятью у программистов подразумевается оперативная память?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ага. За редкими исключениями, которые сейчас неважны. (Когда становятся важными, таких вопросов уже не появляется). Другое дело -- вопрос, какую область адресов занимает стек. (Как правило -- нижние адреса)